# Dapper error executing stored procedure with params of varchar type

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, dapper

I'm getting the following error

```
"Error converting data type nvarchar(max) to int.
2023-10-19 StartDate
2023-10-19 EndDate
Start ConvertedDate 2023-10-19
End ConvertedDate 2023-10-19"
```

I'm trying to execute a stored procedure by sending some dynamic parameters; the parameters sent are `string`s; the stored procedure expects the `varchar` type for those parameters;

Here is the code that I'm trying to execute:

```
var parameters = new DynamicParameters();
parameters.Add("Code", diaryUserCode, DbType.String);
parameters.Add("SDate", new DbString() { Value = startDate, IsAnsi = true }, DbType.AnsiString);
parameters.Add("EDate", new DbString() { Value = endDate, IsAnsi = true }, DbType.AnsiString);
parameters.Add("jsonResult", DbType.String, direction: ParameterDirection.Output);
await connection.ExecuteAsync
(procedureName, parameters, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
```

and here is the procedure signature

```
CREATE   PROCEDURE [dbo].[Test] (
@Code VARCHAR(30)
,@SDate VARCHAR(30)
,@EDate VARCHAR(30)
,@jsonResult NVARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT
)
AS
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```cs
parameters.Add("jsonResult", dbType: DbType.String, size: -1, 
    direction: ParameterDirection.Output);
```

(you were passing the *value* as `16`, the integer value of `DbType.String` - and you weren't specifying the "max" part)